# How to append two XML attributes of type number into datetime format using dataweave

Tags: xml, datetime, mule, dataweave

I am trying to append two XML attributes of type number. Then I want to saved them as a datetime format using Dataweave. Output format is also XML.

Comment: Can you please add an example so that I have a clear picture of your requirement

Comment: my XML input is which is of type integer                                                                 <TRANS_DATE>20141121</TRANS_DATE>
                                                                <TRANS_TIME>110000</TRANS_TIME> I have to append this two atrribute And stored them in single attribute 'date_time' as a datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

If below is the input -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
<TRANS_DATE>20141121</TRANS_DATE> 
<TRANS_TIME>110000</TRANS_TIME>
</root>
```

Then you can do like below to get datetime -

```
{
    tdate: (payload.root.TRANS_DATE ++ payload.root.TRANS_TIME)
                as :localdatetime {format:"yyyyMMddHHmmss"}
}
```

It will output like below or you can also reformat that localdatetime into any string format you like -

```
<tdate>2014-11-21T11:00:00</tdate>
```

Hope this help!